# Every collection of periodic sets $A_n \subset \Bbb{N}$ (minus a common point), that avoids...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\{A_n\}$ be a set of subsets of $\Bbb{N}$ each of which are *periodic* except for a common point.  That is to say, there exists one and only one $x_0$, such that for each $n$, if $x \in A_n, x \neq x_0,$ then $x + T \in A_n$ for some period $T \in \Bbb{N}$ that depends on $n$.

Then if for every finite subcollection $B = \{A_n\}_{n =1\dots N}$, there are an infinite number of solutions $\{x,y\}$ such that $x - y = c$, disjoint from $\bigcup_{B}A_n$, then the same is true of $\bigcup_{n \geq 1} A_n$.  Is this true, how can we prove it?

Comment: Your problem is formulated quite bad. However, I think I found a counterexample. Simply take $A_n=4\Bbb{N}$ for all $n$, $c=1$. If you want the $A_n$'s to be distinct, take $A_n=4^n\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: @Crostul: Why doesn't the infinite collections of pairs $(x,y)=(4k+3,4k+2)$, $k$ any natural number, invalidate your counterexample?

Comment: Because I thought that "the same holds for $\bigcup A_n$" meant that solution should lie in $\bigcup A_n$. Now I understand what you mean.

Comment: Ok. No problem. The phrasing of the question could be improved. I simply think that my interpretation makes the problem more interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the claim is false. Consider the following. Select $A_1=3\Bbb{N}$,
$A_2=5\Bbb{N}$, $A_3=7\Bbb{N}$, $A_4=11\Bbb{N}$ et cetera $A_k=p\Bbb{N}$ with the multiplier $p$ is the $k$th odd prime. Clearly $p\Bbb{N}$ has period $p$.

Let us study the case $c=1$. If we select a finite subcollection of the sets $A_i$, say those corresponding to the set of odd primes $S=\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_m\}$, then let us set $M=p_1p_2\cdots p_m$, $x_k=kM+2$ and $y_k=kM+1$, where the parameter $k$ can be any positive integer.

We have $x_k\equiv 2\pmod{p}$ and $y_k\equiv1\pmod p$ for all $k$ and all $p\in S$. Therefore both $x_k$ and $y_k$ are outside the union $\bigcup_{p\in S}p\Bbb{N}$. Clearly $x-y=1=c$, so there are infinitely many solutions $(x,y)$.

OTOH, when $x-y=1$ one of the positive integers $x, y$ is odd. If $y=1$, then $x=2$, but otherwise that odd integer is divisible by some odd prime. Therefore $(x,y)=(2,1)$ is the only solution in the complement of the union of the sets $A_i$.